# One (or few) word expression for products you don't know you need

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'd like to find a very simple, preferably one word (or few words) expression for products that you don't know you need until you see them. Examples are:

- electronic face cleanser
- sleep enhancing app
- the iPhone
- Nike+ sensor
- a Louis Vuitton handbag
- an open heart tourbillon watch

These products are great, but before you knew they existed you didn't think you needed them. Now that you are aware of them you need them.

I'm thinking *awareness-dependent* or *marketing-driven*, but these are not cutting it. *Luxury* doesn't necessarily apply either. Diamonds are a luxury but they don't need marketing, you know they exist and they are much like commodities.

What I'm looking for is something that describes that a product price has a big marketing content, but not in a negative way (i.e. not "crap you don't need").

Comment: Superfluous comes to mind, but that doesn't quite describe a need.

Comment: Yeah, it indeed has to do with your discretionary income, but superfluous is not necessarily a good word to describe this. I'm also looking for something positive.

Comment: How-did-I-ever-manage-withoutables. I'm suggesting a non-word because if you've managed without them till now, they're almost certainly not a need, especially if hard selling is involved.

Comment: junk-I-really-*can*-do-without. Edit: oh, I just re-read your last sentence. How about *frivolities*?

Comment: I think this is part of a marketing strategy. You make them need a product! "When people don't know they need something, you don't need increased brand awareness... you need increased need/want awareness, followed by solution/product awareness, and only then should you be looking to raise brand awareness." [moz.com](http://moz.com/blog/building-consumer-awareness)

Comment: @ermanen, agreed. "Marketed" can work here.

Comment: "Nonessentials" could work. You don't _need_ it, but you  might feel like you do.

Comment: After the novelty wears off, we call them appliances.

Comment: The obvious positive-spin version of "crap you don't need" is "crap you need (you think)."

Answer (score 3):

> **frippery** *noun* showy or unnecessary ornament in architecture, dress, or language.
>
> <sub>http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/frippery</sub>

Comment: Can you link to, or at least identify, the dictionary you got this definition from?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20frippery

Answer (score 0):

While it's not quite the same thing, consider *[fad](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fad)*

> An intense and widely shared enthusiasm for something, especially one that is short-lived and without basis in the object’s qualities; a craze *Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Fads gain their cachet from the enthusiasm of others and tend to fade rather soon.  Your concept has at least the potential of independent benefit and possible staying power.